# Find and replace multiple values, according to table value - excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like a FORMULA that change letters according to table of values that i make.

**example:**
êíöä = LOVE (because i made a table that show: ê=L, í=O, ö=V, ä=E).

**example- Picture:**
[image]

As you can see in the picture above,
**AB1** - the word I want to decode.
**AB2** - the end result that I want to get.
**Note:** The result is obtained by replacing all the letters in AB1 cell according to the table in A1: Z2.

Thank you. Appreciate your help...

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok, sorry for the inconvenience. I thought I might be able to find help here. I dont need VBA. I looked all over the internet for something that help me try to solve it myself, but I found nothing. That's why I ask for  your help ...
Have a perfect day :)